# Регулярное выражение (Поиск: HEAD)

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Простенькое регулярное выражение:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0)\\s(HEAD)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("0 HEAD");
String d="";
if (m.find()) {
     d=m.group(2);
}
if (d=="HEAD") {
    d="OK";
}
```

Но, к сожалению, d!="HEAD".
Где ошибка?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В Java строки - это объекты, и их нужно сравнивать через `.equals`. В вашем случае условие должно быть следующим:

```
if (d.equals("HEAD")) {
    d = "OK";
}
```

Comment: Тоже эти грабли словил, когда на Java начал писать.  )

Comment: а если 

String a = "a";
String a2 = "a";

a == a2 ??

Comment: @Gorets, это скорее всего будет верно, так как оптимизация поместит в а2 указатель на уже существующую строку, но в общем случае не гарантируется, что две одинаковые строки обязательно имеют одинаковый указатель.

Comment: Спасибо! Ну и вдогонку по строкам: как быть с !=, >= и т.п.?

Comment: !someString.equals("someText")
Ну а как сравнить "больше или равно" для строк - представления не имею... Если только по длите. У строк есть поле length;

Comment: @Gorets в вашем утверждении возможно допущение которое упомянул @ReinRaus но если бы у нас в отделе увидели такую строчку то лично сам начальник отдела бил бы ногами по мозгам.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, сравнивать строки можно методом `compareTo`. 

    someString.compareTo(someOtherString);

[Документация][1]

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: кстати, в С# можно сравнивать строки через ==

Comment: Понятно. А если в строке цифра, то её сначала нужно преобразовать, например в int, а затем уже сравнивать с >, < ?

Comment: >кстати, в С# можно сравнивать строки через ==

признаться, несколько удивлён, что в Java это не так

Comment: Обязательно переводите в числовой тип, ибо Java считает, что `"12300000" < "1234"`.

Comment: @DreamChild, в C# можно сравнивать строки по содержимому через `==` только благодаря наличию в C# перегрузки операторов. В Java перегрузки операторов нет, поэтому `==` сравнивает только по ссылкам. За исключением случая сравнения двух строковых литералов, две идентичные строки (`a.equals(b)`) в Java не равны (`a != b`).